# Insert a value to a column by condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I am attempting to fill in a new column in my dataset. I have a dataset containing information on football matches. There is a column called "Stadium", which has various stadium names. I wish to add a new column which contains the country of which the stadium is located within. My set looks something like this

```
Match ID       Stadium     
1              Anfield
2              Camp Nou
3              Stadio Olimpico
4              Anfield   
5              Emirates
```

I am attempting to create a new column looking like this:

```
Match ID       Stadium            Country
1              Anfield              England
2              Camp Nou             Spain
3              Stadio Olimpico      Italy
4              Anfield              England
5              Emirates             England
```

There is only a handful of stadiums but many rows, meaning I am trying to find a way to avoid inserting the values manually. Any tips?

Comment: How do we know in which country the stadium are? do you have another data set?

Comment: Create a look-up table with a `Stadium` column and a `Country` column giving the location of each stadium, call it `stadium_lookup`. Then do `library(dplyr); your_old_data %>% left_join(stadium_lookup)`. Or in base R `your_old_data |> merge(stadium_lookup, all.x = TRUE)`.

Comment: @Maël As I mentioned, there is only a handful of stadiums and I know the countries

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the unique stadium names from your data, manually create a vector with the country for each of those stadiums, then join them using Stadium as a key.

```r
library(dplyr)

# Example data
df <- data.frame(`Match ID` = 1:12,
                 Stadium = rep(c("Stadio Olympico", "Anfield",
                                 "Emirates"), 4))


# Get the unique stadium names in a vector
unique_stadiums <- df %>% pull(Stadium) %>% unique()

unique_stadiums
#> [1] "Stadio Olympico" "Anfield"         "Emirates"

# Manually create a vector of country names corresponding to each element of
# the unique stadum name vector. Ordering matters here!
countries <- c("Italy", "England", "England")

# Place them both into a data.frame
lookup <- data.frame(Stadium = unique_stadiums, Country = countries)

# Join the country names to the original data on the stadium key
left_join(x = df, y = lookup, by = "Stadium")
#>    Match.ID         Stadium Country
#> 1         1 Stadio Olympico   Italy
#> 2         2         Anfield England
#> 3         3        Emirates England
#> 4         4 Stadio Olympico   Italy
#> 5         5         Anfield England
#> 6         6        Emirates England
#> 7         7 Stadio Olympico   Italy
#> 8         8         Anfield England
#> 9         9        Emirates England
#> 10       10 Stadio Olympico   Italy
#> 11       11         Anfield England
#> 12       12        Emirates England
```